# Data set having menu items (food) and corresponding image?

Tags: machine-learning, images, food

I am working on identifying menu item names for food from their images. Is there any public/private (that I can buy) data set available for supervised learning?

I have this [data set](http://neelj.com/projects/menumatch/data/), but I'm looking for a larger one.

Answer (score 1):

The New York Public Library has a restaurant menu collection and it's one of the largest in the world. Check it out [here](https://public.enigma.com/browse/new-york-public-library-menus/e6bd6c47-0bb2-4f18-a746-c7eb02f18619). I believe the source site has images of [the menus](http://menus.nypl.org/menus).

(Full disclosure - I work for Enigma Public)